# grails integer field default validation

Tags: validation, grails, integer, constraints

I have a grails domain class that looks like:

```
class Person {
  String name
  int age
}
```

When I show the default "create" view (using scaffolding), the age field shows as a required field (with an asterisk next to it). Is there a way to make it show up as non-required and default to blank?

I've tried adding

```
constraints = {
    age blank:true, nullable:true
}
```

This results in the field being allowed to be empty but it still shows up with the asterisk next to it.

Comment: The `blank` constraint only applies to String properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `int` is a primitive type and cannot be blank. You would have to change it to an `Integer`, then a null value would mean that it's blank.